# how to read objectId of a field from one collection and insert that objectid as field to another collection?

Tags: node.js, json, database, mongodb, collections

how to read objectId of a field from one collection and insert that objectid as field to another collection?
I have a collection called student which have objectId name address and teacherId as fields. also I have another collection teacher with objectId name designation. how can I take objectId of teacher from teacher collection and insert it into the field in the student collection.I am trying to get it objectId in this format like  ObjectId("5e97f6636e554578590b24758ae9")…

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ? What are your inputs for this ? `teacher name` ?

Comment: mongodb version is v4

Comment: teacher collection have fields- objectId, name

Comment: student collection have fields -- objectId, name, address, teacherId

Comment: I want to get the objectId of a teacher from teacher collection and need to insert that id in the field of teacherId in the student collection